# Create a new table with the inner join data in hive - I am getting an error

Tags: sql, join, hive, inner-join, create-table

```
SELECT 
    stock_prices_uday.trading_date, stock_companies_uday.symbol,
    stock_companies_uday.company_name, stock_companies_uday.headquarter,
    stock_companies_uday.sector, stock_companies_uday.sub_industry,
    stock_prices_uday.open, stock_prices_uday.close, 
    stock_prices_uday.low, stock_prices_uday.high 
INTO 
    JOIN1_UDAY
FROM 
    STOCK_PRICES_UDAY 
INNER JOIN 
    STOCK_COMPANIES_UDAY ON stock_companies_uday.symbol = stock_prices_uday.symbol;
```

and I'm getting an error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:1 cannot recognize input near 'INTO' 'JOIN1_UDAY' 'FROM' in expression specification

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't support `INTO`.  Use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)):

```
CREATE TABLE JOIN1_UDAY as
    SELECT stock_prices_uday.trading_date, stock_companies_uday.symbol ,stock_companies_uday.company_name,
        stock_companies_uday.headquarter,stock_companies_uday.sector,stock_companies_uday.sub_industry,stock_prices_uday.open,
        stock_prices_uday.close,stock_prices_uday.low,stock_prices_uday.high 
        INTO JOIN1_UDAY
        FROM STOCK_PRICES_UDAY INNER JOIN 
             STOCK_COMPANIES_UDAY 
             ON stock_companies_uday.symbol = stock_prices_uday.symbol;
```